# How to hide SplashScreen in React Native when fonts are loaded using Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I am developing a React Native app using Expo and I am facing an issue with hiding the SplashScreen. I want to hide the SplashScreen only after the fonts are loaded in my app. I have tried using the expo-font library and the useFonts hook to load the fonts asynchronously. However, I'm having trouble finding the right place to call the **SplashScreen.hideAsync()** method when the fonts are loaded.

I want to ensure that the SplashScreen.hideAsync() method is called only once when the fonts are fully loaded.

Could someone please guide me on how to correctly implement the logic to hide the SplashScreen when the fonts are loaded? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

here is the expo tutorial i'm following: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/font/

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";

import LoginScreen from "./screens/LoginScreen";
import OnboardingScreen from "./screens/OnboardingScreen";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
const AppStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const [isAppFirstLaunched, setIsAppFirstLaunched] = useState(null);

// loaddata ...

  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    "cera-Black": require("./assets/fonts/CeraProBlack.otf"),
    "cera-Medium": require("./assets/fonts/CeraProMedium.otf"),
    "cera-Light": require("./assets/fonts/CeraProLight.otf"),
    "cera-Bold": require("./assets/fonts/CeraProBold.otf"),
    "Poppins-Bold": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf"),
    "Poppins-SemiBold": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf"),
  });

  const handleOnLayout = useCallback(async () => {
    if (fontsLoaded) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync(); //hide the splashscreen
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded]);

  if (!fontsLoaded) return null;

  return (
    isAppFirstLaunched != null && (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <AppStack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
          {isAppFirstLaunched && (
            <AppStack.Screen name="OnBoarding" component={OnboardingScreen} />
          )}
          {/* <AppStack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} /> */}
          <AppStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        </AppStack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    )
  );
}
```

I need to know where to call handleOnLayout function to hide the splashscreen, as for now, my app is stuck on the splashScreen.

Answer (score 0):

for now i used a useEffect hook to get the job done, and it's working;

i'm calling useEffect after the handleLayout function.
i'm not sure if this is the right way to do this or not, still waiting for any suggestions.

```
useEffect(() => {
    handleOnLayout();
  }, [fontsLoaded]);
```